# why it is not showing data form api link

Tags: node.js, api, https, backend

I am running this in node.js. sometimes it shows results and sometimes not without any changes in code. the port is running all the time but maybe HTTPS request is not sent all the time.

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const https = require("https");

app.get("/", function(req,res){
    const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=dd6e31b3a79cab7vdy5736fd7ecgfc3563g2u&units=metric"
    
    https.get(url, function(res){
    console.log(res.statusCode);

    res.on("data", function(data){
        const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
        const temp = weatherData.main.temp
        const des = weatherData.weather[0].description
        console.log(temp)
        response.send("the temp in london is " + temp + " . ")
    })
})
    res.send("server is up");
})
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("your port is ready");
} )
```

Comment: When it "sometimes not" shows results, what _exactly_ happens? Do you get JSON but it's empty ? Do you get nothing? What is the payload that is returned by the API? What's the status code? What's the value of `data`? What does the network and console tab look like in your browser?

Comment: For https you need to provide certs or generate a self-signed certificate, see this guide: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/